# Javascript Getting a string into kb format

Tags: javascript, string, byte

I am new to javascript and I just wanted to convert a string into a format that a person like me can read.  Here is an example of what I am trying to do...

string2size(string){
//some awesome coding I have no clue how to make
return awesomeAnswer
}

now the return should give me something like  56 bytes or 12kb or 1mb depending how much the string is.

so if the string is...
string = "there was an old woman who lived in a shoe";
then string2size(string) should return something like 3kb.

Now I know there has been a utf8 talk and I wouldn't object to and addition of that to the function.

I have tried google and Yahoo searches but they talk of using php but I really need it for javascript.  I do thank anyone for their time.
-Teske

Comment: 'there was an old woman who lived in a shoe' is 42 bytes, not 3kb.

Your whole post is only 736 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

First list the units you want to use. For example:

```
// 1024-based units. Kibibyte, Mebibyte etc.
//
var BINARY_UNITS= [1024, 'Ki', 'Mi', 'Gi', 'Ti', 'Pi', 'Ei', 'Zi', 'Yo'];

// SI units, also Hard Disc Manufacturers' rip-off kilobytes
//
var SI_UNITS= [1000, 'k', 'M', 'G', 'T', 'P', 'E', 'Z', 'Y'];
```

Then make a function to find and divide by the biggest suitable unit for a number:

```
function unitify(n, units) {
    for (var i= units.length; i-->1;) {
        var unit= Math.pow(units[0], i);
        if (n>=unit)
            return Math.floor(n/unit)+units[i];
    }
    return n; // no prefix, single units
}
```

Then call on a length:

```
var desc= 'File, '+unitify(content.length, UNITS_BINARY)+'B';
desc+= ' or in SI, '+unitify(content.length, UNITS_SI)+'B';

// eg. File, 977KiB or in SI 1MB
```

I'm not sure what you mean with UTF-8, but if you want to find out the length of a character string as encoded to bytes you'll have to encode that string to UTF-8 yourself. Luckily there is a cheap trick to get a UTF-8 encoder in JavaScript:

```
var bytes= unescape(encodeURIComponent(chars));
alert(unitify(bytes, BINARY_UNITS)+'B');
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will help you.

```
function getStringBytes(string) {
   var bytes = 0;
   var i;

     for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
       var c = fixedCharCodeAt(string, i);
       // in accordance with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description
       bytes += c === false ? 0 :
                c <= 0x007f ? 1 :
                c <= 0x07FF ? 2 :
                c <= 0xFFFF ? 3 :
             c <= 0x1FFFFF ? 4 :
             c <= 0x3FFFFFF ? 5 : 6;
  }
  return bytes;
}

function fixedCharCodeAt (str, idx) {
  // ex. fixedCharCodeAt ('\uD800\uDC00', 0); // 65536
  // ex. fixedCharCodeAt ('\uD800\uDC00', 1); // false
  idx = idx || 0;
  var code = str.charCodeAt(idx);
  var hi, low;
  if (0xD800 <= code && code <= 0xDBFF) { // High surrogate (could change last hex to 0xDB7F to treat high private surrogates as single characters)
      hi = code;
      low = str.charCodeAt(idx + 1);
      if (isNaN(low)) {
          throw new Error('High surrogate not followed by low surrogate');
      }
      return ((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;
  }
  if (0xDC00 <= code && code <= 0xDFFF) { // Low surrogate
      return false;
  }
  return code;
}
```

Comment: Hi Pavel, this code looks awesome! Can you explain why you needed the method fixedCharCodeAt?

Comment: Hi Kirk, fixedCharCodeAt returns character code point. We need code point for determination of bytes size. See wiki page for more details http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description